# Why "if" check doesn't prevent IndexError in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Ut8.png)

This is "IndexError: string index out of range"

**Below the code:**

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message[0] == message[-1] or message is None:
        return True
    return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

**Below the Output of the above Code**

```
True
False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-026229c3b5af> in <module>
      6 print(first_and_last("else"))
      7 print(first_and_last("tree"))
----> 8 print(first_and_last(""))

<ipython-input-9-026229c3b5af> in first_and_last(message)
      1 def first_and_last(message):
----> 2     if message[0] == message[-1] or message is None:
      3         return True
      4     return False
      5 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `if message or message[0] == message[-1]:`

Comment: `message` will not be `None` if it's an empty string, and you need to swap your logic around, check for the empty string *first*

Comment: Or just `if message[:1] == message[-1:]:`

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'or' condition. In 'or' condition, it first checks the 1st statement that is mentioned. It is checking if the 1st and the last element of the string are same or not. If the 1st statement satisfies (only if valid input is given - non-empty string), it will enter into the if condition without checking the 2nd statement. But if the 1st statement fails (1st and last element of the string are not same), it then checks for the 2nd statement.

But, in this case, the 1st statement is not getting the valid input ie it is getting an empty string. Due to invalid input (empty string), it is throwing error. It checks if the statements are true or not only if a valid input is given. If an invalid input is given then it will stop execution and throws the error.

You can make slight change in the code and get the desired output.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message:
        if message[0] == message[-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

Refer to the below snapshot for the output

[image]